# Flask Session will not Persist

Tags: python, flask, session-variables

I have recently deployed my first Flask application (first web application ever actually), one problem I am running into and haven't had luck tracking down is related to sessions.

What I am doing is when the user logs in I set `session['user'] = user_id` and what is happening is I occasionally get a key error when making a request involving that session key. If I try to make the request again the session key is there and the request works fine. I have done research and set the `app.config['SERVER_NAME']` to my domain and made sure the `secret_key` was static, it was dynamic before.

This does not happen when on my local development server so I am a bit stumped at this point.

Comment: How is your application deployed?

Comment: @JoeDoherty I used the following digitalocean tutorial, this was my first deployment. [Digitalocean Flask Depoyment Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem was that I had the key static in my init which caused it to work in dev but in production in the .wsgi it was still dynmaic, I have changed this and all seems to be working now.

Comment: I see you've already got to the bottom :) you can approve your own answer

Comment: @JoeDoherty Thanks, says I have to wait a day so tomorrow I will.

Comment: @jsm1th I am running into the same problem, can you share some actual code as I don't understand what you mean by having the key static in the init..

Comment: what do you mean by setting the secret key from static to dynamic?

Comment: any code or hands on solution for this stupid problem ?